# Bitdefender says Pagespeed-mod.com certificate expired

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, bitdefender

Bitdefender says Pagespeed-mod.com certificate expired.  Its been blocking [www.pagespeed-mod.com](http://www.pagespeed-mod.com) for days now whenever I'm browsing the web.  I use Windows 10 and Chrome browser.  My system date/time is correct.
I've googled the issue and can't find anything except issues for servers. I'm not running a webserver. It doesn't seem to be happening to anyone else.
I have a feeling it will be embarrassingly simple....

I tried resetting my date/time, rebooting, uninstalling the last thing I installed (a USB/serial driver) restarting Chrome, restarting the PC...

Comment: Your question doesn't belong here and should be moved to [super user](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here. I decided to switch to Firefox to see whether the issue persists, and it seems that Firefox does not have that problem. You can also make an exception for the [www.pagespeed-mod.com](http://www.pagespeed-mod.com), which disables the annoying pop-ups, although I am not sure if that compromises any safety.

I personally go with Firefox for now and hope the issue will be fixed in the future.